# Python re.match only matches before the first \n

Tags: python, arrays, regex, python-3.x

I'm trying to wrap ping with Python (3.7.4) using `subprocess` and `re`.

The `stdout` from the `subprocess` function is bytes array so I had to change the regex type to match the case.

```py
    import subprocess,re

    out = subprocess.run(['ping', '-c', '1', '8.8.8.8'], capture_output=True)
    print(out.stdout)
    match = re.match(br'P(..)G', out.stdout, re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE)
    if match:
        print(match.groups())

    match = re.match(br'trans(.)', out.stdout, re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE)
    if match:
        print(match.groups())
```

The actual output from the `ping` command:

`b'PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.\n64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=53 time=60.7 ms\n\n--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---\n1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms\nrtt min/avg/max/mdev = 60.665/60.665/60.665/0.000 ms\n'`

The first output of `match.groups`:

```
(b'IN',)
```

The second one is empty (should be `(b'm',)`), in fact, everything after the first `\n` cannot be matched.

Notice I have `re.MULTILINE`, converting to `str` using `str()` or `.decode()` didn't have any effect on the output.

Checked with several different online tools, they all worked, any ideas?

Comment: You aren't compiling a regex to match. Also, multiline doesn't do what you seem to think it does...it controls the behavior of ^ and $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `match` the matching start from the first position, your variable doesn't start with `trans` and this is why it didn't mach it, use `.*?trans(.)` to indicate that trans is in middle of the text, but I think you should use search:

```
   match = re.search(br'trans(.)', out.stdout)
```

**Note:**

- `re.DOTALL` is only used when you want to include `\n` in `.`, this mean `.` will match any character including `\n`.
- `re.MULTILINE`  by default `^` match the begin of the text, and `$` the end of the text, but when you compile your `REGEX` with this flag,
  `^` will match the begin of line and `$` the end of line (`\n`).

The problem in your case was the way match work check this example:

```
import re

pattern = r'HELLO (\w+)'

print(re.match(pattern, 'HELLO X').groups())  # work fine because the text start with HELLO 
m = re.match(pattern, 'CHELLO X')
print(m is None)  # didn't mach because the Text didn't start with HELLO
```

match start the matching from the first position when you don't specify that the `Hello` is preceded by some characters.

To explain `DOTALL`:

```
import re

text = '\nHELLO X'
pattern = re.compile(r'.*?HELLO (\w+)')
pattern_dotall = re.compile(r'.*?HELLO (\w+)', re.DOTALL)

print(re.match(pattern, text) is None)  # True: . don't match \n
print(re.match(pattern_dotall, text) is None)  # False: here is included
```

Comment: So why does `.*` doesn't work while `.*?` does? BTW I do need the `re.DOTALL` because of the `.*?` at the beginning.

Comment: The problem was that match start matching from the first position and it's True when you want to match `\n` you should use flag `re.DOTALL` . you just need to `re.DOTALL` flag